# Limiting an attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Tournament model that needs 0, 1, or 2 contacts. I created a Contact model and set `has_many :contacts` on the Tournament and `belongs_to :tournament` on the Contact. The Tournament `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts`.

However, when I build the form for Tournament I don't quite see how I should do it. I'm thinking about having two `fields_for :contacts` but it feels messy. I also considered having two specific attributes on the Tournament model (something along the line of `primary_contact` and `secondary_contact`) but I'm not sure about how to do that.

Is there a "correct" way to do this? Any suggestions?

I'm on Rails 3.1 BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fields_for :contacts` is the right way to go.

Take advantage of the fact that, if `tournament.contacts` has multiple items, then a single `fields_for :contacts` will show multiple fieldsets.

Then take advantage of the fact that `tournament.contacts.build` will create an unsaved `Contact` and add it to the `contacts` collection. If you do this in the controller before showing the form then your `fields_for` will display this empty contact and use it correctly with its nested attributes

Comment: Works great. This also simplified my code and solved another problem with the contacts part of the form not being populated with values when errors occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't limit the contacts for 2 fields, because I think you should keep the flexibility of adding more contacts for a tournament later

I have done a small example (by using check boxes) between Project to users, you might be able to get idea

https://github.com/sameera207/HABTMsample

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest maybe adding a non-persistent `contact_list` attribute and then you could enter as many contacts as you need separated by commas into one field:

```
has_many :contacts
attr_accessor :contact_list

def contact_list=value
  value.split(',').each do |email|
    self.contacts.build(:email => email).save
  end
end

def contact_list
  self.contacts.join(',')
end
```

If you need to enter more information for each contact (not just a name, email, or phone number), then you would need more fields.

The following railscast may help you:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1